# How to save Multiple Form Data with single button in Asp.Net MVC5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms, entity-framework-6

I have 2 Controllers `Applicants` And `Applicants_academic_record`.

When user click on **Continue** in `Applicants` Controller, it takes the user to **Create** Method of `Applicants_academic_record` .

When user Clicks on **Back** Button , it takes user back to **Form** of `Applicants` Controller.

I want to perform three tasks.

1. **Continue** button should takes the user to other Controller but it should not save the data in Database but it should hold it.
2. **Back** button should takes the user back to `Applicants` Controller and populates the fields with data that users entered earlier.
3. **Create** Button at 2nd form should save the data at once. Means data of Current form and also of previous form.

This is my Applicants Form.
[image: Applicants Controller]

This is my Applicants_Academic_record Form. 
[image: Academic_Record Controller]

Comment: Your 'Continue' button needs to submit the form to a controller method that saves the date to a repository (a separate database table or `Session` etc) and then redirect to the `Create()` method (and pass along a value that identifies the temporary record so it can be retrieved later). But why do you want 2 separate pages?

Comment: @StephenMuecke , i am working on **Online Registration** . so i have two Tables in Database with same name as Controllers. Their relationship is `one-to-many`, so i have to separate these forms because one **Applicant** can have multiple **Academic_Records** .

Comment: That makes no difference. If your requirement is that you must create one Academic Record when you first create the Applicant, create a view model containing all properties and have one view/form and save everything in one action.

Comment: Or better, have one form to create the Applicant and design the view to allow multiple Academic Records to be created (refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308) for an example)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use jQuery

1. Continue button: hide the first form and show the second form ( academic details)
2. Back button: hide the second form and show the first
3. Save: make ur post action to take two objects the applicant and the academic details

I don't know if the both forms will be submitted , you need to test it.

In case it did not work with you , you can use ajax call

If you need further help, you are welcome to ask

Hope this will help you